# convert array of json to javaScript object

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I had problem i need to generate  a js object from array of json objects using c#
 i.e 
   this is json :-

```
[
     { 
         "FieldName": "lastPrice",
         "LookupID": 1,
         "FieldAr": "اخر سعر",
         "FieldEn": "last price"
     },
     {
         "FieldName": "currentPrice",
         "LookupID": 2,
         "FieldAr": "السعر الحالي",
         "FieldEn": "current price"
     }
]
```

and what I need is :

```
 var localAr = {};
 local.lastPrice /*field name*/ = "اخر سعر"; // fieldAr
 var  localEn = {};
 local.lastPrice /*field name*/ = "last price"; //FieldEn
```

I have no idea how to do this or even what i supposed search for

Comment: Have a look at JSON.parse that is supported by modern browsers.

Comment: @Lukas what should i do in c#

Comment: You want to create this in Javascript or C#? What;s the matter. Please explain your scenario/requirement more clearly.

Comment: @vnikhil  i want to create this in c# and then send save this in file and the javascript user will just include this file and use this object

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using square-bracket notation, which allows you to use a string as a property name

```js
var input = [
     { 
         "FieldName": "lastPrice",
         "LookupID": 1,
         "FieldAr": "اخر سعر",
         "FieldEn": "last price"
     },
     {
         "FieldName": "currentPrice",
         "LookupID": 2,
         "FieldAr": "السعر الحالي",
         "FieldEn": "current price"
     }
];
var fieldAr = {};
for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    var item = input[i];
    fieldAr[item.FieldName] = item.FieldAr;
}
console.log(fieldAr)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Response**

Ok, so you want to accomplish something similar in C# as to the solution posted below. The first thing you would need to do is deserialize the JSON into an object. The easiest way would be to use [JSON.NET and convert to a dynamic object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm) and then convert it to a dictionary type. You would return the dictionary as JSON (either using MVC's JSON method or by converting back using JSON.NET)

```
var json = GetJson();
dynamic fields = JArray.Parse(json);
var myObj = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
   myObj.Add((string)field["FieldName"], field["FieldAr"]);
}

Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj));
```

**Original Response**
If I understand correctly, you want the JSON being returned into a javascript 
object that looks similar to the format:

```
var newObj = {
   lastPrice: "اخر سعر",
   currentPrice:  "السعر الحالي"
};
```

If this is correct, I would parse the object into a JSON object then create a new object from it. For example,

```
var fields= JSON.parse(data);
var myObj = {};

for(var index = 0; index < fields.length; fields++){
   myObj[fields[index].FieldName] = fields[index].FieldAr;
}
```

Comment: that exactly what i want to do but in c# code and send it to javascript user to deal with it

Comment: What are the shapes of the object that you get from your repository? I.e., are you using a data row, reading from a file, or getting from an object? Or is it already in JSON and you need to parse it?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight-forward, just loop through each entry and store the property value based on the property name.

```js
// Assume you called JSON.parse(json) to get the following parsed data...
var parsedData = [{
    "FieldName": "lastPrice",
    "LookupID": 1,
    "FieldAr": "اخر سعر",
    "FieldEn": "last price"
}, {
    "FieldName": "currentPrice",
    "LookupID": 2,
    "FieldAr": "السعر الحالي",
    "FieldEn": "current price"
}];


var strings = {
 en: {},
    ar: {}
};

for(var i = 0; i<parsedData.length;i++){
   var data = parsedData[i];
    strings.en[data.FieldName] = data.FieldEn;
    strings.ar[data.FieldName] = data.FieldAr;
}

console.log(strings);
```

That will allow you to access properties based on locale and field name, like so:

```
console.log(strings.en.lastPrice); // "last price"
console.log(strings.ar.lastPrice); // "اخر سعر"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class in c# for your object, instantiate 2 instances of the class with your required property values, add to a list, then use the [Newtonsoft.Json library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) to serialize the list. Simples :)

```
public class Field{ 
    public string FieldName {get;set;}
    public int LookupID {get;set;}
    public string FieldAr {get;set;}
    public string FieldEn {get;set;}
}

var field1 = new Field(){ FieldName = "lastPrice", LookupID = 1, FieldAr = "اخر سعر", FieldEn = "last price" };
//init other field here

var fields = new List<Field>() {field1};

var fieldsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fields);
```